# Upgrading from JPA 2.1 to JPA 2.2

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.2

I'm having issues upgrading to JPA 2.2. I'm using eclipselink and changed the version in my pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I also updated the persistence.xml to point to the correct version of the xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
<persistence-unit name="foo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>my.entity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:foo/data;create=true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd" />

        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The issue is that I'm getting the following error message:

> The persistence.xml file does not have supported content for this JPA platform.

I've looked through the eclipselink documentation and nothing is jumping out at me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like an Eclipse issue:   https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=522302

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you don't need to change the persistence.xml at all, only the libraries on the classpath.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error message after upgrading from JPA 2.0 to 2.1; I got rid of it by also upgrading the JPA Platform in the Eclipse Project JPA settings to EclipseLink 2.5.x.

Answer (score 0):

Installing an unofficial JPA 2.2 support patch solved my issue

Help > Install New Software >

https://dl.bintray.com/danjaredg/eclipse-jpa2.2/eclipse-4.13/